# How can I keep one specific article always on top on the front page?

Tags: joomla, frontpage, joomla-article

On my Joomla website, I'd like to have a "about our company" article always be the first article on the front page. I want the other articles to shift down in position as new articles are added, but to keep the "about our company" one constantly on top.

I tried setting the order of that article on the front page manager to -1, but it still shifted down when I added a new article.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write that info in a module and publish that module in a position that shows up before the component.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the front page sorted by date? If you do then make the about us article have a created date of 2099-01-01 and make sure you switch off show date for that article

Answer (score 1):

Unless you find an adequate plugin for this specific need, I'm afraid you have to manually modify the template.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the setup, you can use the section or category info as a "fake" article. Enable showing the section/category description in the menu item (it's off by default) and you'll have a text that is always at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggelng with the same issue,... and have found the solution in the joomla documentation.

In the frontpage manager set order number for the article that you want to be "always-on-top" to -1 (minus one). This will make sure it will always have a lower order number than the other articles, even when other people submit articles.

Answer (score 0):

For Joomla 1.5, go to your FrontPage Manager. The article you want to always have at the top, type is -1 in the ORDER column (as William said above). Now next to the name of this column, there is a picture of a floppy disk - you MUST click on this icon to SAVE the order.

Now your WELCOME article is numbered -1 and will always be at the top of your front page.

Answer (score 0):

This question is Google top result, yet Joomla has been upgraded many times since it was asked and answered. Here is a more recent option:

In Joomla 3.4, you can do this by going to the settings of the category that displays the articles, then to its Blog Layout, then set Article Order to Featured Articles Order. This makes featured articles appear above normal articles.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020, one could add Custom Fields (available since Joomla 3.7) to Joomla articles, or just to articles in a certain category, and then modify the template to query this Custom Field and handle articles accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

in the order number in joomla 1.5 setting the order number to a minus figure doesn't work, it keeps reverting back to the default number.